# Why can't I use Wake on LAN on my computer?

Tags: wake-on-lan

I am trying to wake up my computer. Wake on LAN is enabled in that computer's BIOS – actually it's called "Resume On LAN", but it must be the same as Wake On LAN right? The computer doesn't have any operating system installed.

I have turned the computer off (it's still plugged in of course) and I'm trying to switch it on by sending the magic packet. The problem is: It's not working.

It's called "Wake on Lan", so does the computer have to be actually *working* and needs to be in standby mode? Is there no way to remotely power on the computer?

When I run `arp -a`, I don't see it's there either.

Comment: Don't accept an answer if you have a *new* question. People won't care to read it. Just [ask a new one](http://superuser.com/questions/ask), or unaccept the answer you already have here (I'd really suggest asking a new question though).

Comment: @slhck but that "new" questions is 100% related and I accepted and answer which answered both question.

Comment: Maybe I'm having trouble finding it, but where does the answer tell the difference between "Resume on LAN" vs. "Resume on Ring"?

Comment: @slhck mm. I agree with you. There is no direct answer though. So what to do know? :D

Comment: As I said, just *ask a new question*. You will surely get a better answer. Even if it's related to this one, just put in a back-reference. I rolled back your edit, but you can use that as a starting point for your new question! :)

Comment: @slhck my second question was rather rhetorical :DD okay okay and it was partially answered in the link Ofir provided. Won't ask a new question. Thank you for keeping StackExchange clean.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wake-on-LAN#Other_machine_states_and_LAN_wakeup_signals

It is possible that you have to enable another BIOS setting or check the LAN card configuration

Comment: yes, I had to enable Resume on Ring as well.

Answer (score 4):

Computer must be in standby or sleep

Wake, in this case, means wake up from sleep.

Suggest trying s1 or s3 sleep as some power must be running throught the NIC in order for it to receive the magic packet